# Why I can't read json

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to read JSON but I got below error.

```
2019-08-27 13:12:43.352 27379-27379/com.test W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value transcript of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

*JSON*

```
{"transcript":{"text":[{"content":"Flood!","dur":"1.76","start":"2.28"},{"content":"Listen up, there’s a flood coming!","dur":"2.24","start":"4.52"},{"content":"Oy lads, flood!","dur":"1.92","start":"7.88"},{"content":"There’s a flood –","dur":"1.24","start":"10.72"},{"content":"Maurice, they’re not listening.","dur":"1.84","start":"13.96"},{"content":"We’ve got to give them\na good old-fashioned fish slappin’.","dur":"2.8","start":"15.96"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1.04","start":"20.52"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1","start":"22.32"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1.2","start":"24.12"},{"content":"Double Fish Slap!","dur":"1.24","start":"25.84"},{"content":"See, guys? Flood’s here.","dur":"1.56","start":"27.84"},{"content":"Tub Rider!","dur":"2.48","start":"31.56"},{"content":"SEASON 1\nTHE FLOOD","dur":"1","start":"35.32"},{"content":"Because I’m in a tub!","dur":"1.04","start":"36.48"},{"content":"PREPARE TO BATTLE ON A BOAT","dur":"1.48","start":"37.68"}]}}
```

*Code*

```
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("transcript");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("text");
            Log.w("aaa",String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("content")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: obviously because `transcript` is ot a valid json and that's what you are trying to parse with `new JSONObject("transcript")`

Comment: Did you maybe just forget to put the JSON string instead of "transcript' in line 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your json into a String and then try to parse it :

```
String json = "{\"transcript\":{\"text\":[{\"con ...}";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("transcript");
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("text"); 
    Log.w("aaa",String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("content")));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Remember to escape your double quotes with backslash

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = "{"transcript":{"text":[{"content":"Flood!","dur":"1.76","start":"2.28"},{"content":"Listen up, there’s a flood coming!","dur":"2.24","start":"4.52"},{"content":"Oy lads, flood!","dur":"1.92","start":"7.88"},{"content":"There’s a flood –","dur":"1.24","start":"10.72"},{"content":"Maurice, they’re not listening.","dur":"1.84","start":"13.96"},{"content":"We’ve got to give them\na good old-fashioned fish slappin’.","dur":"2.8","start":"15.96"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1.04","start":"20.52"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1","start":"22.32"},{"content":"Fish Slap!","dur":"1.2","start":"24.12"},{"content":"Double Fish Slap!","dur":"1.24","start":"25.84"},{"content":"See, guys? Flood’s here.","dur":"1.56","start":"27.84"},{"content":"Tub Rider!","dur":"2.48","start":"31.56"},{"content":"SEASON 1\nTHE FLOOD","dur":"1","start":"35.32"},{"content":"Because I’m in a tub!","dur":"1.04","start":"36.48"},{"content":"PREPARE TO BATTLE ON A BOAT","dur":"1.48","start":"37.68"}]}}"

       try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject transcript = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transcript")
           JSONArray jsonArray = transcript.getJSONArray("text");
            Log.w("aaa",String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("content")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @user11983213 if this answer is working then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and code you've provided, I understand that you are new and unfamiliar with the JSON APIs in Android. For this, I suggest you read the official documentation and get yourself familiar with **org.json** API (`JSONObject`, `JSONArray`):

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray

After, you may want to practice and follow some tutorials on serialization/deserialization of JSON in Android using the **org.json** API. Here is a fairly complete tutorial I just found for you on the net (just an example, there are literally hundreds out there):

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("content"))`

you could use :
`jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("content")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass json string to Json object first.

please refer the below code, it might work for you.

```
 try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"transcript\":{\"text\":[{\"content\":\"Flood!\",\"dur\":\"1.76\",\"start\":\"2.28\"},{\"content\":\"Listen up, there�s a flood coming!\",\"dur\":\"2.24\",\"start\":\"4.52\"},{\"content\":\"Oy lads, flood!\",\"dur\":\"1.92\",\"start\":\"7.88\"},{\"content\":\"There�s a flood �\",\"dur\":\"1.24\",\"start\":\"10.72\"},{\"content\":\"Maurice, they�re not listening.\",\"dur\":\"1.84\",\"start\":\"13.96\"},{\"content\":\"We�ve got to give them\\na good old-fashioned fish slappin�.\",\"dur\":\"2.8\",\"start\":\"15.96\"},{\"content\":\"Fish Slap!\",\"dur\":\"1.04\",\"start\":\"20.52\"},{\"content\":\"Fish Slap!\",\"dur\":\"1\",\"start\":\"22.32\"},{\"content\":\"Fish Slap!\",\"dur\":\"1.2\",\"start\":\"24.12\"},{\"content\":\"Double Fish Slap!\",\"dur\":\"1.24\",\"start\":\"25.84\"},{\"content\":\"See, guys? Flood�s here.\",\"dur\":\"1.56\",\"start\":\"27.84\"},{\"content\":\"Tub Rider!\",\"dur\":\"2.48\",\"start\":\"31.56\"},{\"content\":\"SEASON 1\\nTHE FLOOD\",\"dur\":\"1\",\"start\":\"35.32\"},{\"content\":\"Because I�m in a tub!\",\"dur\":\"1.04\",\"start\":\"36.48\"},{\"content\":\"PREPARE TO BATTLE ON A BOAT\",\"dur\":\"1.48\",\"start\":\"37.68\"}]}}");
        JSONObject transcriptObject = obj.getJSONObject("transcript");
        Log.d("transcript object",transcriptObject.toString());
        JSONArray textArray = transcriptObject.getJSONArray("text");
        Log.d("text array",textArray.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use GSON library for json parsing.